# How do i unit test a react app that has all the text fields in the children components?

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, jsdom

I have created a react application that has all the logic (like onchange functions) in the parent and all the html rendering in the children components.

In order to test if the right state changes are happening i have to enter text to the input fields and enter values but the only problem is I dont know how to access the children elements when i mount the parent in js dom.

Should i move logic into the child components or should i only unit test the functions of the parent component?

This is from the parent

```
    render() {
    if (!this.state.accessTokenEntered) {
        return <AccessTokenPage _onChange={this._onChange}
                                accessToken={this.state.inputs.accessToken}
                                env={this.state.inputs.env}
                                _onFirstClick={this._onFirstClick}/>;
```

and this is the child

```
const AccessToken = props =>(
<Layout>
    <Input name={"accessToken"} displayName={"Access Token"} _onChange={props._onChange}
           value={props.accessToken}/>


    <DropDown name={"env"} displayName={"Environment"} _onChange={props._onChange}
              data={['ppe', 'prod']} multiple={false}
              value={props.env}/>

    <br/>

    <div style={{"textAlign": "center"}}>
        <input type="button" onClick={props._onFirstClick} className="btn btn-primary" value="Submit"/>
    </div>
</Layout>
);
```

and this is the childs child

```
const Input = props => (
<div className="form-group row">
    <label className="col-xs-2 col-form-label">{props.displayName}</label>

    <div className="col-xs-10">
        <input name={props.name} className="form-control" value={props.value}
               onChange={props._onChange}/></div>
</div>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be testing your child component. When the onChange event of the textbox is simulated, test if the onChange prop is called. This can be done by creating a mock or spy for the onChange prop.

An example test is shown below:

Mocking a prop.

```
beforeEach(() => {
    onAdd = jest.fn();
    add = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<Add onAdd={onAdd} />);
  });
```

Test if the mock method is called:

```
it('Button click calls onAdd', () => {
    const button = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(add, 'button');
    const input = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(add, 'input');
    input.value = 'Name 4';
    TestUtils.Simulate.change(input);
    TestUtils.Simulate.click(button);
    expect(onAdd).toBeCalledWith(input.value);
  });
```

I am using Jest and React TestUtils. Similar code is available for enzyme in my [github project](https://github.com/vijayst/react-test).

Comment: I can test the lowest level child with spies, but can I  test the middle level component as well? As its just  made of other components I found it very hard to test